# Yii2 GridView - Change search filters to onchange event instead of submit

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am using GridView widget in yii2 to show the data.

I have filters on all the columns and I want to reload the page on `onchange` event, at the moment, I need to hit enter or focus out in order to make the search work (it's page reload not ajax based search).

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
      'name',
      'email', /// list goes on.
```

[image]

Comment: Use Yii2-pjax..

Answer (score 1):

add this before the GridView widget Pjax

```
 <?php PJax::begin() ?>
 <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
      'name',
      'email', /// list goes on.
<?php PJax::end() ?>
```

But remmber you should return the same view in order to emulate ajax. 
Here is more example. [PJax tutorial](http://blog.neattutorials.com/yii2-pjax-tutorial/)

Comment: Here is PJax documentation [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html)